# SQL Database - Organize Database correctly over different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I want to create a Relational Database (mySQL-Workbench and MariaDB-Server), which organizes the inventory of an Online-Bookstore.

I already identified the different attributes each product (mostly books) will have and thought about organizing that database in at least three different tables 1. productInformation 2. marketInformation 3. stockInformation:

**But maybe someone got a better idea?**

1.

- id INT(10)
- isbn10 VARCHAR(10)
- isbn13 VARCHAR(13)
- asin VARCHAR(10)
- titel VARCHAR(300)
- autors ?         **Question: A product may have 0 or 1 or 2 or X Authors, that will be different for each product, how can I handle that? As far as i know sql does not have an list or array datatype..**
- publisher VARCHAR(100)
- edition INT(5)
- productForm VARCHAR(100)
- binding VARCHAR(100)
- productHeight INT(5)
- productWidth INT(5)
- productWeight INT(5)
- numberOfPages INT(5)
- language VARCHAR(50)
- mediafiles IMAGE

---

2. 

- priceDE DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceAT DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceCH DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceAMZused DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceAMZnew DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceM DECIMAL(7,2)
- priceR DECIMAL(7,2)
- fixedBookPrice BOOL
- available BOOL
- salesrank varchar(20)
- NumberOfNewOffers INT(5)
- NumberOfUsedOffers INT(5)

---

3. 

- InventoryQuantity INT(5)
- StorageLocation VARCHAR(50)
- Sku VARCHAR(50)
- Condition VARCHAR(50)
- ConditionDescription VARCHAR(500)
- CanBeSoldAsNew BOOL
- Supplier VARCHAR(50)
- Shipper VARCHAR(50)

---

Those attributes, let's call them salesHistory, can only be accessed through another database which organizes the orders of that bookstore. That leads me to a second question, **should the orders be organized in a completely different database or would it be better to organize it in the same database with different tables?** The orders will be accessed through the Amazon/eBay API.

- NumberOfSalesNew INT(10)
- NumberOfSalesUsed INT(10)
- NumberOfSalesM INT(10)
- NumberOfSalesR INT(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should store author's information in a separate table with the foreign key relationship to the first table.

SHEET 1:
If edition, productform and binding are of fixed options then you can use enum in front end and save corresponding integer values in the table. But if those could be change in future you can use separate table for each of them with an integer primary key and then store the primary key in the table as foreign key reference.

If I got you right there is single only single record in all three tables. So you can consider single table instead of three tables. Please let me know if I got it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for first answer that's really helpful already! Since I didn't start designing the database yet, I just created an example in Excel I hope that works - I got 2 examples line 2 and 3 and some explanation in line 5 I hope that's enough - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13OrIscT6doRPByilaUUkFAvT0ZyHvj1vcrLZhh6csmI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks again really much! You're right some attributes are of fixed options e.g product form and binding, but edition could be any number from 1 to ~1000 or so, so I guess an int would be better for edition right? But I will use enum where possible, that's a good point!  I just made an example with those 2 entries, in the final database will be more than 50 000 products - is that what you mean with the single record?

Comment: Nope. What I understood is there are one row in each table for ISBN10 `3551354073`. If that's the case there is no use of separate tables. But if against a single ISBN10 there are multiple rows in other two tables you need to use foreign key in those tables.

Comment: Ah okay, no it could be that there are more entries with the same ISBN10, In my example I thought about using the Excel index as a foreign key, so in my case there is only one row in each table for the index "2" and index "3" - as soon as I will convert this in a real db I will have to determine a foreign key. - I thought it's probably more "safer" to use different tables.

Comment: Agree with you. you can use integer autoincrement column in table 1 then use this value in other two tables as foreign key.

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks a lot! And would u agree on me with how i divided the attributes in those three tables? I would add the table for the authors and maybe a table for images depending on if I store the image itself or the path